# How to convert @[System::ContainerStartTime] to UTC

Tags: ssis

I am using `@[System::ContainerStartTime]` to acquire the start time of my ETL-process.
For this, I create a new column using *Derived Column*.

However, SSIS only allows to store the result as a `datetime` and thus does not provide timezone information.

How can I can convert this to an UTC datetime similar to `GETUTCDATE()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Integer variable User::TimeShift, assign it with SSIS Expression Task using the following expression

```
DATEDIFF("Second",GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
```

Then use this variable in Derived Column transformation

```
DATEADD("Second",@[User::TimeShift], <LocalDateTimeColumn>)
```

By first initializing offset variable and latter reusing it you avoid multiple calls to `GETDATE()` which do not improve performance. If performance is not a concern, you can do Derived Column without intermediate variable

```
DATEADD("Second",DATEDIFF("Second",GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()), <LocalDateTimeColumn>)
```

Comment: Thanks - I will go for the one line solution as long as I am prototyping.